# How to use a header file in c

Tags: c, gcc, header

I defined a method in class MyStrLen.c and implemented it and i declared for it in the head file MyStrLen.h, what i wanted is to use a method from MyStrLen in another class MyStrCmp.c
but it shows a compilation error in the shell when i try to make the o file.

MyStr.h

```
  int inputLen(char* myStr);
```

MyStr.c

```
int inputLen(char* myStr)
{
  ....
  ....
}
```

MyStrCmp.c

```
 #include "MyStr"
void method()
{
 inputLen(someinput)
}
```

and this is the compilation error

**MyStrCmp.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `inputLen'
MyStrCmp.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to`inputLen'
MyStrCmp.c:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `inputLen'
MyStrCmp.c:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to`inputLen'**

Comment: And the compilation error is... ?

Comment: it looks like your error has more to do with the fact that you aren't linking one of the files.

Answer (score 2):

Right, the basic checklist goes as follows:

- Does `MyStrCmp.c` include the `MyStr.h` file: `#include "MyStr.h"` should be at the top of the file (along side `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`)
- Does `MyStr.c` do the same? By that I mean include its own header file (`#include "MyStr.h"`)
- Are the 3 files mentioned (`MyStrCmp.c`, `MyStr.c` and `MyStr.h`) in the same directory?
- Are you passing both the `MyStrCmp.c` file and the `MyStr.c` file to gcc?

If the answer to all 4 of these questions is yes, then:

```
$ gcc -o MyStrCmp -Wall MyStrCmp.c MyStr.c -std=c99
```

Should work. Because of the way you've written the `inputLen` function (in `MyStr.c`), it's written as a file that can be compiled externally, or separatly (`gcc -o MyStr.c`, to produce an o-file). As a result, the linking has to be done explicitly, by passing both source files to the compiler. By the way, more details can be found in [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559250/c-error-undefined-reference-to-function-but-it-is-defined)
Basically, open a terminal window, and enter the following commands:

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test/
$ touch MyStr.c && touch MyStr.h && touch MyStrCmp.c
$ vim MyStr.c MyStr.h -O
```

I use Vim, you can use your preferred editor, but that's besides the point.
In the `MyStr.h` file, you type:

```
int inputLen(char* myStr);
```

Save and close it, then edit the `MyStr.c` file, and define your actual function:

```
#include "MyStr.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int inputLen(char *myStr)
{
    printf("%s\n", myStr);
    return strlen(myStr);
}
```

Save & close, then edit the `MyStrCmp.c` file, and write something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "MyStr.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv )
{
    const char *test = "Some test-string";
    int l = 0;
    l = inputLen(test);
    printf("The printed string is %d long\n", l);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Then compile with the command I provided above. This worked just fine for me...

Comment: +1 for showing the correct way to link files.

Answer (score 1):

In `MyStrCmp.c`, put this at the top:

```
#include "MyStr.h"
```

Comment: i did that but still didn't work

Comment: If those are the only files you've got: `gcc -Wall MyStr.c MyStrCmp.c -o programoutput`. It looks like you didn't compile the MyStr.c file yet.

Comment: @somebody You did what? `#include "MyStr"` or `#include "MyStr.h"`? Also, are you developing on an OS where file names are case-sensitive?

Comment: @somebody: Where are the files in respect to your `MyStrCmp.c` file? are both the `MyStr.h` and `MyStr.c` file in the same directory?

Answer (score 1):

Your "MyStr.h" should have this:
`extern int inputLen(char* myStr);`

and your "MyStr.c"
should have `#include<MyStr.h>`
and your MyStrCmp.c should also have `#include<MyStr.h>`

provided that, all the headers and sources are in the same directory!

To avoid multiple inclusion confusions: use header guards

```
#ifndef MYSTR_H
#define MYSTR_H

extern int inputLen(char* myStr);

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer may be that you have not used the right compilation command.

You must use the -c flag (if you are using gcc) to create a .o file, otherwise gcc will try to link the executable and without knowing about MyStr.c it will fail to find the inputLen function.

Try compiling Mystr.c and MyStrCmp.c separately using -c and then linking the .o files.

You mention in a comment that you "did compile it", but you must make sure the two files get combined by the linker.