# CS50 - Compiling Issues

Tags: c, cs50

I am currently taking the cs50 Harvard course via EDX and am working on the Cash/Greedy Algorithm problem from PSET1/Week1. I have it all written out and I keep getting this error;

```
~/pset1/ $ clang -o cash cash.c -lcs50
/tmp/cash-4f9816.o: In function `main':
cash.c:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `round'
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is my code.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void)
    {

float dollars;
do
{
    dollars = get_float("Change: ");
}
while (dollars <= 0);


int cents = round(dollars * 100);
int coins = 0;

while (cents >= 25)
{
    coins ++;
    cents -= 25;
}


while (cents >= 10)
{
    coins ++;
    cents -= 10;
}


while (cents >= 5)
{
    coins ++;
    cents -= 5;
}


while (cents >= 1)
{
    coins ++;
    cents -= 1;
}

printf("You Will Receive %i Coin(s)\n)", coins);
 }
```

Can someone help me figure this out without breaking the Harvard honor code?

Comment: See [Compilation error on function round](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/21058/compilation-error-on-function-round-in-greedy-c-pset1) (tl;dr [link with -lm](https://manual.cs50.io/3/round)).

Comment: This exercise has been posted so many times in StackOverflow that solving it without breaking the Harvard honor code is like trying not to get spoiled about who is Luke Skywalker's father in 2020.

Comment: Why are you executing "clang" instead of "make"?

Answer (score 1):

Use `make cash`. It will link both libraries (`math` and `cs50`).

In your compiling command, you link only cs50 library with `-lcs50`. `Round` function comes within library `math`. That's why compiler fails in finding reference to `round`.

There are some good [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559250/c-error-undefined-reference-to-function-but-it-is-defined) to understand why `undefined reference to` occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You are not linking the math library in your clang command either add a -lmath or use the make command.