# undefined reference to WinMain c programming language in vscode

Tags: c, undefined-reference, winmain

Altough I save my project, I get these errors

When I run parametric_stack_arr.c I got this error

```
D:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64- 
w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64- mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a 
-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e): 
undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I run main.c I got this error

```
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccq0uYEM.o:main.c:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `push'
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccq0uYEM.o:main.c:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `print'
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccq0uYEM.o:main.c:(.text+0x96): undefined reference to `pop'
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccq0uYEM.o:main.c:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `push'
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccq0uYEM.o:main.c:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `print'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is my code

I import `parametric_stack_arr.h` to `main.c`

main.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "parametric_stack_arr.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    printf("hello");
    stack s1;
    stack s2;  
    s1.size = 2;
    s1.arr = NULL;
    s1.top =0;

    s2.size = 2;
    s2.arr = NULL;
    s2.top =0;
    
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {   
        push(i*10, &s1);
    }

    print(&s1);

    int j;
    for(j=1; j<=10; j++)
    {   
        push(pop(&s1), &s2);
    }
   
    print(&s2);


    return 0;
}
```

I import `parametric_stack_arr.h` to `parametric_stack_arr.c`

parametric_stack_arr.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "parametric_stack_arr.h"




int pop(stack *s)
{
    if(s->arr = NULL){
        printf("error");
        return -1;
    }

    if(s->top <= s->size/4)
    {
        int *arr2 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*(s->size)/2);
        int j;
        for(j =0; j<(s->size); j++)
        {
            arr2[j]=s->arr[j];
        }
        free(s->arr);
        s->arr = arr2;
        s->size /= 2;
    }
    return s->arr[--s->top];
}

void push(int x, stack *s)
{
    if(s->arr = NULL)
    {
        s->arr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    }
    if(s->top >= s->size)
    {
        int *arr2 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*(s->size)*2);
        int j;
        for(j =0; j<s->size; j++)
        {
            arr2[j]=s->arr[j];
        }
        free(s->arr);
        s->arr = arr2;
        s->size *= 2;
    }
    s->arr[s->top++] = x;
}

void print(stack *s)
{
    printf("\nsize : %d\n", s->size);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<s->top;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", s->arr[i]);
    }
}
```

I add my function prototypes to `parametric_stack_arr.h`

```
#ifndef __PARAMETRIC_STACK_ARR_H
#define __PARAMETRIC_STACK_ARR_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



typedef struct
{
    int size;
    int top;
    int *arr;

}stack;

int pop(stack *s);
void push(int x, stack *s);
void print(stack *s);

#endif
```

Comment: Where is `parametric_stack_arr.c` and how is this compiled? Have you already read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559250/c-error-undefined-reference-to-function-but-it-is-defined  ?

Comment: all files are in the same folder@Bob__

Comment: I applied this but I still get these errors

Comment: @baseroglu, can you paste the content of `parametric_stack_arr.c`?

Comment: How do you build your program? Please show complete command line. If you just use VSCode as is, there will probably not multiple sources compiled and linked together.

Comment: Please show the exact full error messages

Comment: A) show your actual error. B) show how you build your code. This looks like a linking error.

Comment: OTOH `WinMain` is required if you use certain Windows API functions, which you haven't. So perhaps the project is not set up properly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22160071/775806 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816

Comment: @JHBonarius  I added my error messages

Comment: *When I run parametric_stack_arr.c* This C file does not contain a valid program. You cannot build and run it. You must compiler and link both files together. You will need to adjust the json files in VSCode to produce a binary holding both files. And as it was asked already: **HOW** do you try to run/compile your code?

Comment: You are getting linker errors, when you try to make an executable from each of the source files individually.

Comment: Okey , How can I adjust the json files?  @Gerhardh

Comment: If the programmer is required to manually change some JSON then that's the opposite of what an IDE is supposed to be doing - the main reason why use IDEs is so that we don't have to mess around with make files manually. If they replaced the make file with some JSON, then that's taking one step forward and two steps back...

Comment: @Lundin they don't consider it an IDE [themselves](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/supporting/FAQ#_what-is-the-difference-between-visual-studio-code-and-visual-studio-ide).

Comment: @Bob__ Ok in that case it seems like a pretty pointless product... beginners should use a proper IDE.