# Undefined reference to .o files in subdir when compiling

Tags: c, makefile, object-files

My project architecture :

```
project_folder/
 |--bin/
 |--src/
 |    |-----module1/
 |    |      |----> module1.c
 |    |      |----> module1.h
 |    |      |----> module1.o
 |    |      |----> makefile
 |    |-----module2/
 |    |      |----> module2.c
 |    |      |----> module2.h
 |    |      |----> module2.o
 |    |      |----> makefile
 |-- makefile
 |-- main.c
```

When I make my project It correctly builds the modules of my project and then when I want to compile the whole project I have undefined reference to modules' functions.

I think the error comes from my CC command in my head makefile so here is my makefile :

```
export CC = gcc

PACKAGES = module1 module2

MAIN = main.c

EXEC = bin

all: $(PACKAGES) $(EXEC)

$(PACKAGES):
    @$(MAKE) $(MAKECMDGOALS) -C $@

$(EXEC): $(MAIN)
    $(CC) $(MAIN) -o $(EXEC)

.PHONY: all clean $(PACKAGES)

clean: $(PACKAGES)
```

Error is :

```
/usr/bin/ld: /project_folder/main.c:line undefined reference to `module1_fct1`
```

Do y have any advice ?

Comment: Please show the actual error message. But in any case, your `$(CC) $(MAIN) -o $(EXEC)` command needs to also be passed all the `.o` files of the modules. You are not doing that.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5559274/1256234) help?  In the rule to build `$(EXEC)`, you also need to add the source file where `module1_fct1` is defined.  Adding a function declaration in a header file is not enough.

Comment: Yes but I want to recursively add the sources

Comment: You have to list `module1/module1.o` and `module2/module2.o` as dependencies of `$(EXEC)` and include them in the compiler/linker command arguments.  You also need to ensure there are rules to make them. Your modules rules wont help much; the directories exist so they will never need to be executed.