# call a function from header file in C

Tags: c, operating-system, riscv, xv6

In xv6, I have `hello.h` inside kernel folder, `main.c` inside user folder.
The error is in `main.c`.

**kernel/hello.h:**

```
void hello();
```

**kernel/hello.c:**

```
void hello(){
    printf("hello\n);
}
```

Now I want to call function `hello()`. But get error.

**user/main.c:**

```
#include "kernel/types.h"
#include "kernel/stat.h"
#include "user/user.h"
#include "kernel/hello.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  hello(); // error here (undefined reference to `hello')
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C error: undefined reference to function, but it IS defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559250/c-error-undefined-reference-to-function-but-it-is-defined)

Comment: Note that `void hello();` is not a complete function prototype in current versions of C. You probably meant `void hello(void);` (and the same in the .c file).

Comment: @pmacfarlane It is, however, (still) a valid function declaration; in this specific case, it should be no problem to do it this way.

Comment: Warning, you should not store your `hello` module in `kernel` directory since it's only user code, not privileged code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile `hello.c` and `main.c` files **and** link them together.

```
gcc -o myprog main.c hello.c

./myprog
```

Answer (score 0):

undefined reference error usually occurs when a symbol is known to the linker but fails to be associated to an actual definition.

in the context of `main.c`, `hello` was known. The compiler is happy because it's compiling `main.c` and so doesn't need to know the specifics of hello. But the linker does, because it's job is to make the different pieces fit together.

Make sure you have compiled both files `main.c` and `hello.c` and that both are known to the linker stage (with gcc, it's whenever you do not compile with the `-c` flag).

For instance, it could be

```
gcc main.c  -c -o main.o
gcc hello.c -c -o hello.o
gcc main.o hello.o -o a.out
```

or even, because gcc is pretty lenient : `gcc main.c hello.c`